# Using ChartKickjs with Sinatra and HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, haml, chartkick

I'm trying to use [ChartKick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) in my [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) application. When trying to create a control such as a barchart I get an error stating

> undefined method `id' for {:cash=>82, :securities=>58}:Hash file:
>   buffer.rb location: parse_object_ref line: 323

Any suggestions on resolving this?

app.rb

```
...
 @estimates = {:cash => cash_estimate, :securities=> sec_estimate}
haml :results
...
```

results.haml

```
%label="By saving cash you will be able to retire at the age of  #{@estimates[:cash]}}."
%br
%label="Choosing to invest your savings in stock securities may allow you to retire at #{@estimates[:securities]}."

%barchart[@estimates]

%script{:type => 'text/javascript', :src => '//www.google.com/jsapi'}
%script{:type => 'text/javascript', :src => '/js/chartkick.js'}
```

Comment: Also, you can omit the `=` and double quotes on your labels. The variable will be interpolated anyway. http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_

Comment: @mus thanks for the advice. I'm rather new to ruby so always looking to make my code look more ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to haml docs this:

```
%barchart[@estimates]
```

Will try to create a `<barchart>` html tag and use `@estimates` to set its id and class.

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#object_reference_

What I think you are trying to achieve is this:

```
= bar_chart @estimates
```